# Error 1004, Select method of object Range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying a simple transpose macro and I got this error, tried a couple of solutions but still hitting a rock.

Here is the code.

```
Sub pastetrasp(Zone As String) 
    Dim asdf1 As Range
    Dim n As Integer

    If Zone = "CF" Then
        Set asdf1 = Range("Q1:Q4")
        Set asdf2 = Range("P1:P4")
        Set asdf3 = Range("O1:O4")
        n = 1
    End If  

    Sheets("Data").Select
    Sheets("Data").asdf1.Select    ' ERROR
    ActiveCell.Copy
    Sheets("example").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -n).Select
end sub
```

Comment: Just asdf1.Select Sheets("Data") has no idea what asdf1 is!

Comment: `asdf1.Select` by itself will work as long as the parent sheet is active (and `asdf1` is not `Nothing` - ie. it's set to a range). What do you want this code to do? Typically it's unnecessary to select/activate anything if you just want to copy data to another location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ActiveCell` cannot reference a range. And you also don't need to use `Select`.

Use `asdf1.Copy` to copy

And for  `PasteSpecial`, you need to precede it with a range but you are selecting a sheet before that line.

Instead, you can do something like

`Sheets("example").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=True`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked!, However it only copies the first value of the vector, might have something wrong with the paste command

Comment: I tried using asdf1.select, but it gives me an error. Tried printig the adress and that works.

Comment: Oh, activating the "example" sheet before seting the ranges fixed it, like the range comes with a sheet "atached" to it